# No such file or class on classpath: com.<name>.<abc>.<classname> when executing scala jar using command line

Tags: scala

I am getting the

> No such file or class on classpath: com

when executing the scala uber jar using the below command.

> scala -classpath kafka-scala-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.< name >.< abc >.KafkaAggregateConsumerApp

I am using scala 2.11.12

Answer (score 0):

From the error it looks like you might have a space after the `com` in your command. Re-check that please.

Also, if you already have an uber jar you can run the jar directly using the `java` command.

```
java -cp kafka-scala-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.foo.bar.KafkaAggregateConsumerApp
```